# Rsync to remote server and change file / directory ownerships

Tags: linux, rsync, chown

I am using Rsync to deploy to a remote server, which is working. However the file and directory ownership always replaces old files with root:root

I need the ownership of all files and folders transferred to the destination folder on the remote server to be changed to www-data:www-data.

I need to access the server as root via ssh, as I don't have the password for www-data. At the moment I have to transfer all the files, and then run the chown command in Terminal afterwards, but I'd like to automate this.

At the moment I am trying the following, but it doesn't work or transfer any files.

'rsync -rlDvz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress --exclude `exclude` --exclude .htaccess --exclude site/accounts `source` root@`ip`:`dest` && chown -R `user`:`group` `dest`'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `rsync -aAX`

This should transfer both ownership/group and extended attribute (eg: selinux)

Answer (score 0):

Rsync has the --usermap and --groupmap in version 3.1.0 and above

https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.1.0-NEWS

So if you have 3.1 or above version, you can use either **--usermap=www-data:www-data** or **--chown=www-data:www-data** in rsync command like below

```
rsync --chown=user:group -rlDvz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress source user@ip:dest
```